# A strange thing about Nullable Boolean type, And and Or in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a strange problem about the following codes:

```
!isActive.HasValue || (isActive.HasValue && x.IsActive == isActive.Value)
```

`isActive` is a `bool?` type, so if `isActive` is `null`, then I will get the following error:

> Nullable object must have a value.

Any idea about that? Thanks for your help!

Update 1:

```
public static List<User> Select(int userId, bool? isActive = null)
{
    var dl = DataLayer.GetDataContext();
    return dl.Users.Where(x => x.ID == userId
                && (!isActive.HasValue || (isActive.HasValue && x.IsActive == isActive.Value))).ToList();
}
```

This is the sample function I got this error. I know it is so strange! If I change like below, it will work:

```
!isActive.HasValue || (isActive.HasValue && x.IsActive == isActive)
```

I understand this error mean, but I don't understand why. It should work I think. So I call it strange thing!

Update 2:

1. x.IsActive is bool type, not bool?. I am sure on it :)
2. DataLayer.GetDataContext() is for Linq to SQL.

Is it possible it is because I am using SQL Server?

Thanks guys for your help so far.

Comment: At compile time? Execution time? It's not clear what's going on here. Could you post a short but complete example?

Comment: Can you post the full piece of code and which line it is failing at?

Comment: What is the type of `x.IsActive`?

Comment: The way I see it, is `x` null? Or is `isActive` a field/property and you have some multithreading going on reassigning that field?

Comment: If @justin-niessner's answer didn't suffice, try posting a more complete code example. From the error, you're clearly accessing isActive when it is null, but your code doesn't show that.

Comment: Based on your update, are you _sure_ that the `DataLayer.GetDataContext.Users` collection never returns `null` values for `x`?

Comment: @DaxFohl x.IsActive is bool

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I don't think so. If Users or x is null, why I didn't get error if I change x.IsActive == isActive?

Comment: @Jian Yeah, I just read that now. It's almost as if the expression `isActive.HasValue && x.IsActive == isActive.Value` is being evaluated in reverse order. EDIT: Is this hitting a database or Linq-to-Entities/SQL or is it Linq-to-Objects?

Comment: how is the `User.IsActive` property implemented?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair it is Linq-to-SQL

Comment: @Jian is there something you're not telling us? The caps are different in your argument `userId` vs your usage `userID`, so I've got the feeling you're editing the code before posting, and may be leaving something important out.

Comment: @DaxFohl Yes, I have changes some codes, but just some variable names. Actually, userId is just userID, I made a mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Split that condition into multiple statements so *you* can see what exactly fails. Than you may need less code in sample.

Comment: @Jian I think this may be an issue with how Linq-to-SQL evaluates your expressions to generate its SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's Linq-to-SQL, then perhaps it's not short-circuiting or evaluating the expression parts in the proper order. I haven't used it, but from what I understand it *reads* the content of your lambda expressions and converts it to a close equivalent SQL statement; it does not actually *execute* it like C# code.

Even so, doing the check for each item seems like a bit much when the value is fixed. You could rewrite the method as such:

```
public static List<User> Select(int userId, bool? isActive = null)
{
    var dl = DataLayer.GetDataContext();
    var users = dl.Users.Where(x => x.ID == userID);

    if (!isActive.HasValue)
    {
        return users.ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        bool isActiveValue = isActive.Value;
        return users.Where(x => x.IsActive == isActiveValue).ToList();
    }
}
```

This way there's no additional constraints on the generated SQL query if they're not applicable. EDIT: Updated it so in addition, there are no nullable booleans being passed into your query whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different `isActive` values in your code, so it looks like you're missing the `x` on the second check:

```
!isActive.HasValue || (x.isActive.HasValue && (x.IsActive == isActive.Value))
                   ----^
```

I've also added parentheses around the equality check just to eliminate any confusion around the order or operations

Comment: I don't think that's it exactly. If `x.IsActive` is a nullable boolean, you can still directly compare it if it's null, just not access its `.Value` member: `bool? isActive = null; Console.WriteLine(isActive == true); //false, no exception`

Comment: @DStanley No, I didn't miss x. isActive is a bool?, but x.isActive is bool.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, it's because of the query builder in LINQ.  There may be a way to execute your intention in one query (in fact it sounds like your updated code in the q does just that), but the straightforward thing to do is to split it into two queries since you know the value of `isActive` beforehand.  That way you don't have to worry about what the query builder may or may not be doing.

For that matter you may as well just make this two separate functions entirely, just to make it harder for future maintainers to accidentally fall into the same trap:

```
public static List<User> Select(int userId)
{
    return DataLayer.GetDataContext().Users.Where(x => x.ID == userId).ToList();
}

public static List<User> Select(int userId, bool isActive)
{
    return DataLayer.GetDataContext().Users.Where(x => x.ID == userId && x.IsActive == isActive).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I think you are right, but I choose another similar answer. Because that on is the first. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're code shouldn't be failing on that line.

I'm guessing it is failing somewhere in your `if` block (I'm assuming that's what this statement is for). Your first condition will return true if `isActive` is `null`. If you then try to use isActive from inside the block, you'll get the Nullable error.

Answer (score 0):

Where does the code fail if you do this?

```
public static List<User> Select(int userId, bool? isActive = null)
{
    var dl = DataLayer.GetDataContext();
    return dl.Users.Where(x => E(userId, isActive, x)).ToList();
}

static bool E(int userId, bool? isActive, User x)
{
    return x.ID == userId && D(isActive, x);
}

static bool D(bool? isActive, User x)
{
    return (!isActive.HasValue || C(isActive, x));
}

static bool C(bool? isActive, User x)
{
    return (isActive.HasValue && B(isActive, x));
}

static bool B(bool? isActive, User x)
{
    return x.IsActive == isActive.Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your debug way. But it is using Linq to SQL, so when I used your codes to debug, I got the following error: Method 'Boolean E(Int32, System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean], DataAccessLayer.User)' has no supported translation to SQL

Answer (score -3):

change its type from bool to bool?

```
bool? IsActive = false;
```

Comment: if it has the `HasValue` property, it's most likely a `bool?` already

Comment: my apologies i dnt notice that..there is some question edit also